# Testing of express controllers where the access the mongoose model?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, testing, mongoose

I want to unit test my express controllers independently. But they interact with the mongoose models. So the question is how can I test them? For example -

```
const Model = require('./../models/mymodels');

const controller = (req, res) => {
const body = req.body;
const foo = new Model(body);
foo.save().then(foo => res.send(foo)).catch(err => res.send(error));
};
```

So I want to test the funtion `controller` independently.

Answer (score 1):

```
const expect = require('chai').expect;

const Model = require('./../models/mymodels');

describe('controller test', function() {
  it('should be valid if body is correct', function(done) {
    const testBody = {myKey: "myVal"}
    const m = new Model(testBody);

    m.validate(function(err) {
      expect(err.errors).to.not.exist;
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

This is an example, check the chai documents for more examples

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think you misunderstood my question. I want to test my controller function and with the assertion that it 'should call the new Model with the correct arguments' or something like that. You are calling Model in the test that is the unit test for the Model but I want to test the controller so that it should not access the Database, basically, I want to mock the Model so that I can Assert somethings about the calls.

Comment: Only thing that your controller doing in this example is creating an instance of the model. The tests that you are going to write will reflect what your controller does.